# recieving signal SIGSEGV segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{

    int i, j, array[10] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
    modify();

    for (i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        printf("Origional Array is:");
        printf(" %d\n", array[i]);

    }

    modify(array);

    for (i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        printf("New Array:");
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }

    system("pause");
}

modify(int array[10])
{
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j<10; j++)
    {
        array[j] = array[j] * 3;
    }
    return array[j];
}
```

there is no compile time error... but at run time this show signal sigsegv segmentation fault.
please help me...!

Comment: C++ doesn't allow you to have functions without specifying a return type. Ignoring conio, [see here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e275a22f1a13172) for some errors your compiler *should* give you. (Edit) As for your problem, a debugger would be a great help. You can figure out where it crashes and go step by step to that point, watching variable values and understanding why the crash occurs.

Comment: then please help me... can u correct my code..?

Comment: This looks like C code. `modify` has implicit `int` return value. Was there a compiler warning that you ignored?

Comment: Are you ***sure*** your programming in C++? Because if you did then you would get compiler errors.

Comment: compiler not show any error and not warning...!

Comment: You are reading an out of bounds array item in your `modify` function.

Comment: Make sure your IDE is set to all warnings or waning level 4, or that -Wall is on the command line.

Comment: @mirzasalman - *compiler not show any error and not warning.* -- Then this is `C` code and not C++.  C and C++ are two different languages -- this code will not compile if given to a C++ compiler, but will compile if given to an (ANSI 89) C compiler.  Given that it compiles with an ANSI C compiler, then the rules of `C` take over -- rules that do not exist in C++.  So please know the actual language you're using, and tag your posts accordingly (don't put a C++ tag on questions that deal with `C`, and vice-versa).

Answer (score 1):

<sub>[Note that this answer assumes that the code is actually C and not C++]</sub>

There are a few problems with your code.

The fist is this:

```
modify();
```

Here you *call* the function, before you have told the compiler that it exists. Apparently your compiler says it's okay, which it really isn't. What probably is happening is that the compiler deduces (fancy word for "guessing") that the function takes no arguments and returns nothing. I.e. that the declaration look like

```
void modify(void);
```

This "guessing" was allowed in older standards of C, but since the C99 standard this implicit declaration was removed and would give you an error in a compliant compiler.

A little later you do

```
modify(array);
```

which once again calls the function, but since the compiler thinks that the function doesn't take any arguments, none will actually be passed. Which leads to the worst problem of all: In the actual `modify` function you use an argument, but since none is actually passed the variable will not be initialized and you will have *undefined behavior* trying to dereference that pointer (arrays decays to pointers when passed as arguments to functions) and you will most likely have your crash there.

There also the returning from the function:

```
return array[j];
```

Here the value of `j` will be `10` which is *out of bounds* for the array you pass (well, *try* to pass) to the function.

To solve the problem, add the function prototype declaration somewhere before calling the function, a usual place would be in the global scope just before the `main` function. Something like

```
...
int modify(int *array);

int main(void)
{
    ...
}
...
```

And fix the `return` statement in the function.

Comment: @Joachim Just out of curiosity: Well, you're very often propose (of course correct) answers for very individual problems. How does that fit with the generally suspected Q&A scheme to be helpful for future research, and what are your particular points to decide to answer, or just close vote (duplicates aside)?

Comment: From what I remembered, implicit declarations were of the form `int foo();`, namely an integer return and any number of parameters.